# Uploading a file angular way

Tags: angularjs

As far as I know, AngularJS applications are supposed to be single-page. That also should be true for web forms.

I can easily process a text input field:

```js
var app = angular.module('snippet', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = () => {
    $scope.result = $scope.inputText;
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:14pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="snippet">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS snippet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <h1>Enter text:</h1>
      <input ng-model="inputText">
      <input type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="submit">
    </div>    
    <div>
      <h1>Text you have entered:</h1>
      <span>{{result}}</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I change `input type="text"` to `input type="file"` and try to specify a text **file**, the `$scope.result` property remains undefined:

```js
var app = angular.module('snippet', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = () => {
    $scope.result = $scope.inputFile;
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:14pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="snippet">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS snippet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <h1>Enter text:</h1>
      <input type="file" accept=".txt" ng-model="inputFile">
      <input type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="submit">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <h1>Text you have entered:</h1>
      <span>{{result}}</span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

How should I modify the snippet above to make it works with a text file?

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do.  Are you expecting the browser to read the file and set the model to the text contained in the file?

Comment: @Claies basically, yes. I want to initialize the model property from a file, not from a text input field.

Comment: files are *binary*.  in order to do this, you would have to read the file using the browser file api and convert it from binary to text.  this isn't supported by `ng-model`.

Comment: @przno thank you! I wonder why I couldn't find that